# Limitation of tags in an Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

I'm looking for the best practice of tags in Airflow.

1. any limitation on the size of a tag name?
2. how many tags are good for an Airflow DAG?
3. what's a good tag example vs using the naming convention of the DAG's name? For example, which one is better: all Ads teams' dags are tagged with "Ads" or named as ads_XXX_XXX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The max length of a tag is [100 chars](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/dag.py#L117).

As far as a tagging strategy, it's entirely up to you. Not using tags is also a valid option. There is no right or wrong when it comes to naming conventions & tags. Use whatever makes the most sense to you.

They are used to help filter dags so you do not have to rely on the name. You could filter them by team, by task (a "downloader" dag vs a "loading data" dag etc), or any other arbitrary group you think would be useful.